# How do I get the current namespace in Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

```
namespace :baseline do
  INDEX_DIR = index(:baseline) # context
  task(:foo) ...
end
```

How do I get the `:baseline` Symbol in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
namespace :baseline do |namespace|
  scope = namespace.instance_variable_get("@scope")

  INDEX_DIR = index(scope)

  task(:foo) ...
end
```

Comment: You can then use this to get access to the `scope`, which will be an array of the namespaces that this task is nested inside: `namespace.instance_variable_get("@scope")`

Answer (score 4):

There is a much cleaner way now:

```rb
namespace :baseline do
  scope = Rake.application.current_scope
  puts scope.path
end
```

I needed this to define dynamic tasks, so not having to pass the namespace to the block is a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Dmitris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135468/676874) with `Rake.application.current_scope`:

```
namespace :baseline do |namespace|
  scope = namespace.scope.path
  #...
end
```

`scope` will be `"baseline"` (String, not the requested Symbol).

But in rake you can define the namespace with symbol or string, you can also define like this:

```
namespace 'baseline' do |namespace|
  scope = namespace.scope.path
  #...
end
```

The scope will be the same with both definitions.

If you really need the Symbol, you can use `scope.to_sym`.

Answer (score 0):

Years have passed, but improvement is improvement.

If you need the `Rake::NameSpace` object and you don't have access to a namespace object as a param:

```
... do |the_namespace|

end
```

you might do that:

```
scope = Rake.application.current_scope
ns = Rake::NameSpace::new Rake.application, scope
```

Now the `ns` object will provide you methods like `ns.tasks` and so on..